# Refrences for new sql server version in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, dll, sql-server-2012

whats the newer version of these references i can be add on my asp.net project and sqlserver 2012  when i  build my project without changing my target framework but change sql server version and windows server 20003 to 2008 get error for these reference

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum
Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser
Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
```

Answer (score 0):

The refrenced assemblies are have probably a higher version of .net as your project. Check the .net version of your project and the new sqlserver assemblies.